# Data Factory - Kusto - ingest cluster

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer

I have a data factory pipeline that helps us clean our data sources for compliance (cosmos/blobs etc). I want to add kusto clean up as well to this pipeline. There is a purge option in kusto that helps to clean docs but this command can only be run on the Data Management endpoint (https://ingest-[YourClusterName].[Region].kusto.windows.net).

There is an ADF activity for data explorer commands but I cannot select the data management endpoint in the linked service. The auto populate doesn't include ingest cluster (only normal kusto cluster is present) and when entering it manually requires database and other info which is not present for data management endpoint. Is there a way we can select the data management endpoint for the command activity ? If not is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: If the answer below answers your question, please accept it by clicking the "V" icon. If you're still missing info, please add a comment elaborating what info you need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [purge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/data-purge) command is intended for deleting specific rows to comply with compliance such as GDPR requirements.

I assume that when you say clean our data sources in Kusto, you mean dropping temp tables right? In that case, you can use the "[.drop tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/drop-table-command)" command